# Programmatic Check Angular Multi Select DropDown

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I check [angular material multiselelect](https://nileshpatel17.github.io/ng-multiselect-dropdown/) programmatically using typescript.

Currently I get the selected value from server but can't figure out how to set the selected property for particular values

```
 this.userService.getRolebyIdAndName(this.Id,this.RoleName)
.subscribe(
    data => {

      this.loading=false;
   this.manageroles = data.json();

if  (data.json().accessList.length>0){
for(var i=0;i<data.json().accessList.length;i++)
//This has selected value true / false 
//data.json().accessList[i].selected
this.tempDropdown.push({ item_id: data.json().accessList[i].value, 
item_text: data.json().accessList[i].text,selected:true })

  }


  this.dropdownList=this.tempDropdown;


  <ng-multiselect-dropdown
    [placeholder]="'Pages'"
    [data]="dropdownList"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"

  >
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Template change

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown #multiSelect
    [placeholder]="'Pages'"
    [data]="dropdownList"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

component

```
@ViewChild('multiSelect') multiSelect;
this.multiSelect.toggleSelectAll();
```

Comment: check on stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown